# want to access google books from android app

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-books

I am pretty new to android; I would like to access google books
from my android app. Can anyone provide any pointers, sample code, or advice on
how to get going here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably know about the [Books Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html).  Since there are [no samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/GoogleAPIs#Google_Book_Search_API) for using `google-api-java-client` with that API yet (although you can [add one](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/entry?template=Request%20a%20Sample) and get all your friends to 'star' it so that Google pay attention to it), your basic strategy is:

1. [download the samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/GoogleAPIs#Setup_directions) using Mercurial and Maven into your favourite IDE (such as IntelliJ ;- )  *It's worth learning Maven/Mercurial or at least how to set them up for your IDE)*
2. look particularly at the [calendar-v2-atom-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default)
3. create some 'model' classes with [@Key annotations](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html) which mirror the structure of the [elements you'll get in the feed](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html) using the samples as a guide for how to use them

There unfortunately is no shortcut for coming to terms with the elements of the ATOM 'feed'.

### Handy things to know

These include:

1. 'everything is an `<entry/>`
2. `transport.buildGetRequest().execute().parseAs(MyModel.class)` handles your basic needs
3. the @Key annotation can handle any namespace prefixes that you gave to your parser when you set it up (xref lines 96-102 of [CalendarAndroidSample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/CalendarAndroidSample.java?repo=samples) where it sets up the transport and parsers)

Sorry about all the links, but that's what Google development is like!

### Colophon

It's best to think of the `google-api-java-client` as a tool that helps you with all the ugly XML and HTTP plumbing, so that you can *build your own api*.  It's a bit of work, but once you've mastered the GoogleUrl class (just read the source of it and GenericUrl), and the @Key annotations, there isn't actually a lot of *boring* work.  You get down to tin tacs of 'what do I want to actually do with this information' surprisingly quickly.